# Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController' defined in URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Currently I am trying to run my Spring Boot Application. I followed a Tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtUdl9pZwR0

Unfortunately I get an Error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/3.3.2.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySearchController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pagedResourcesAssembler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler]: Factory method 'pagedResourcesAssembler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pageableResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.web.HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver]: Factory method 'pageableResolver' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sortResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.web.HateoasSortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver]: Factory method 'sortResolver' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.User.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.Product.Product

`ExcelController`

```
public class ExcelExporter {
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private XSSFSheet sheet;

    private List<Product> listProducts;

    public ExcelExporter(List<Product> listProducts) {
        this.listProducts = listProducts;
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Products");
    }

    private void writeHeaderRow(){
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBold(true);
        font.setFontHeight(16);
        style.setFont(font);

        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Product ID");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);

        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("Name");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);

        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("Kategorie");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);

        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("Text");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);

        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue("Location");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
    private void writeDataRows(){
        int rowCount = 1;

        for (Product Products : listProducts) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);

            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(Product.getId());

            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(Product.getName());

            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(Product.getCategory());

            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(Product.getText());

            cell = row.createCell(4);
            cell.setCellValue(Product.getLocation());

        }
    }
    public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        writeHeaderRow();
        writeDataRows();

        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

`Product:`

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Entity
@Service
public class Product {
    private static Long id;
    private static String name;
    private static String category;
    private static String text;
    private static String location;

public Product() {}
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public static Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public static String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public static String getLocation() { return location; }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is more Code that could be usefull:

`ProductService`

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    public ProductRepository repo;

    public List<Product> listAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Product product) {
        repo.save(product);
    }

    public Product get(long id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void delete(long id) {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

`ProductRepository`

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Add `@ComponentScan({ "Full Qualified Package Name" })` in your main class and try. *Note* : Full Qualified Package Name should be your package name like : `com.example.test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ExcelExporter should be annotated with `@RestController` tag.

And if you want to use your services annotated with `@Service` tag, you should inject the services with any injection you want or annotated with `@Autowired` in your controller class.

*cant add a comment because of my reputation and you did not mention it.*

Comment: I actually edited my Product class because I forgot important Code. In that case I forgot to add the @Service Annotation. Now a lot of errors are gone. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set JPA annotations on methods you should annotate the entity class with `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`

By default the access is on fields, and no field is defined as an identifier for the Product entity. Hence the error:

```
 No identifier specified for entity: com.Product.Product
```